# conversion of string to decimal

Tags: c, string, serial-port, decimal

I am using RS232 serial communication to rotate the motor. The serial communication is done in strings but i need decimal value for it. Any clues how to proceed.I am coding in c language.i tried using atoi function but its not working.

```
char *p;
```

`int z=atoi(p);`

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually given a string:

```
char * myStr= "123";
```

the way to obtain it's value as an int is:

```
int value=atoi(myStr);
```

Some things important to notice:

the following include is necessary:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and you must be sure that your string is a null terminated string otherwise atoi will crash you program.

You didn't gave us much information but if you're programming a microcontroller (I suspect that since you told us about a motor) you maybe won't want to use stdlib. In that case you might have use a costum function.

Please take a look at the code bellow:

```
int stringToInt(char* nrStr){
int nrChars=0;
while(nrStr[nrChars]!='\0'){
    nrChars++;
}


int result=0;
int i=0;
while(nrStr[i]!='\0'){//while you dont get to the end of the string
    int digit=nrStr[i]-48;//48 is zero ascii code
    int exp=nrChars-i-1;
    int add=digit*power(10,exp);
    result+=add;
    i++;


}
return result;


}
int power(int base, int exp){
int ret=1;
int i;
for(i=0;i<exp;i++){
    ret*=base;
}
return ret;
}
```

This does not use any library functions and does the job. I've done it in 3 minutes and it may have some small error, it's not very efficient and does not verify possible errors, but in principle if you pass the strinToint function a well formed integer as a null terminated string it will output the correct value.

If you're using a library that does have some implementation of a power function do use it instead of the one I gave you since it is not efficient at all.

One last note: if you for some reason need to use it in other basis lets say octal basis, you have to chance the line:

```
int add=digit*power(10,exp);
```

to:

```
 int add=digit*power(8,exp);
```

for hexadecimal this will not work, and implementation of such a function will be significantly different.

Comment: yea dats fine but the string doesnt give the exact ascii value.its showing some garbage value after conversion since its a character constant.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `strtoXXX()` family of functions. If you need `int`, `long` or `long long` or their unsigned variants:

```
long l = strtol("1234567", NULL, 10);
long long ll = strtoll("1234567", NULL, 10);
unsigned long l = strtoul("1234567", NULL, 10);
```

If you need a `float`, `double`, or `long double` use this:

```
float f = strtof("3.1415927", NULL);
double d = strtod("3.1415927", NULL);
```

Manuals [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/strtol.html) and [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtod.html).

Comment: actually the microcontroller doesnt accept this.we need to give the decimal values to the motor to rotate.this decimal value should be serially communicated through gui.

Comment: @user1437027 1. Neither part of that sentence makes sense. 2. How is the "microcontroller not accepting" it?

Comment: microcontroller wont accept strings to run the motor.even if it accepts it would be the ascii or some garbage value. it needs some decimal value.

Comment: @user1437027 What is that "decimal value" you keep talking about? If the string format is not appropriate, store it in an integer (what I've shown here). Or what else would be needed, seriously?

Comment: ok. i am sending the command to the motor through a gui via serial communication. now the microcontroller will receive some string in the receive buffer.but we cannot run the motor using this string value. here we need to convert string to decimal. this decimal value will be given to the motor to turn to certain degree. i hope i am making myself clear.*serial communication is always in strings.*

Comment: @user1437027 And this precisely what these functions do. You need to read about C data types.

Comment: Usually mocricontrollers do have a small amount of memory and therefore using c std lib probably isn't an option...that's probably why he says atoi and strtol don't work...i guess

Comment: @Mppl And why rolling one's own implementation is better then? They're practically the same.

Comment: The point is that when you use a c lib function the lib must be present at the microcontroller and there may not be enough space (to store the lib itself)...

Comment: @Mppl And what do you think, what happens when you write your own implementation? That gets stored into the progmem too...

Comment: You're right but when you use a c lib function 1st it might be that the mc loader copies the hole library to the microcontroller (that is indeed bigger than my implementation of some functions...) 2 nd if it does not copy the hole library to the microcontroller the part it does copy will most probably be bigger that my implementation of some functions...

Comment: @Mppl Modern compilers (rather the **linker**) don't copy over the whole lib, that's just downright brainless, and no, a naive implementation of `atoi()` or `strtol()` is not necessarily bigger, especially in implementations which are designed specifically for embedded systems.

Comment: You're right. It shouldn't be bigger, but many times it is... I remember many times when working with microcontrollers I had to make my own "printf" implementation cause my code + the necessary functions to printf wouldn't fit the available memory and yes I did manage to do a much smaller implementation (10X smaller).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28327/discussion-between-h2co3-and-mppl)